# Deleted all SMS! - unrooted Android 8.0.0 - Recovery Options?

Tags: data-recovery

I was deleting 2 SMS messages, I did long press on the 1st until the blue tick appeared then selected the 2nd SMS. I then quickly went to the top 3 dots to select 'Delete' and the next thing I saw is blue ticks by every SMS and 'Deleting' message on the screen.
The screen refreshed and it was blank - all SMS messages deleted :-(

What are my options to recover them?
I have looked at apps like Fonedog & Dr Fone but after they connect they state root is required.

My phone details;
Model: Mi 5
Android version: 8.0.0 OPR1.170623.032
Android Security patch level: 2018-10-01
MIUI version: MIUI Global 10.2 Stable 10.2.2.0(0AAMIXM)

In Developer options:
OEM unlocking is greyed out but it says "Bootloader is already unlocked" underneath (see screenshot below)
Mi Unlock status says "Unlocked"

[image]

Phone has been left turned off.

If the bootloader is already unlocked - could I try to root the device (with low risk of data loss) then try Fonedog & Dr Fone recovery again?
When I first got the phone I tried Kingo-root and similar apps but they failed to root the device. I didn't take it any further at the time.

OR is there a way I can dump the internal memory flash (NAND?) to pc and use data recovery to find & restore my SMS?

Your help and suggestions greatly appreciated - I had some sentimental messages I would definitely like to recover. I have removed the SIM, turned off Wifi, turned on aircraft mode and phone is turned off unused.

Thank You.

Mark

Comment: fastboot boot twrp.img, get sql database, examine with hex editor. if messages still there change deleted-flag with some forensic tool

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I am following the guide but am stuck at 'fastboot flash recovery twrp.img' - all I get is < waiting for device >. The phone is connected and rebooted into FASTBOOT with the bunny on the screen - but after 1-2 minutes it just restarts.
Before I tried the "adb devices" command and it lists 1 connected device. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: UPDATE: Looks like I got the latest twrp working. I'm viewing the internal storage in file explorer but there is no /data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db showing. What am I doing wrong now? Do I need to allow modifications at the first prompt?

Comment: Sorry I worked it out now. I've found the file - do I copy it off the phone to pc or is there something else I should be doing?  I did search for a twrp users guide but haven't yet found a detailled English one.- if you know of one a link would be great :-)

Comment: db has over 1400 id's & 600 threads (so looks good) all '1' in deleted column! I guess the next step is to get the deleted column changed back to 1 and copy the amended db back to the phone?

Comment: ok. I ran your metadata command and it returned: -rw-rw----    1    671744 Apr 23 14:48 u:object_r:radio_data_file:s0 - I have taken backups and renamed the original db/journal on the phone (so not visible to sys). I have copied the amended db to the phone.
  - How do I update the owner/permissions/secontext on new db file? In twrp file manager there is 'chmod 755' & 'chmod' button

Comment: *'[chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) 1001.1001 mmssms.db; [chmod](http://www.filepermissions.com/articles/understanding-octal-file-permissions) 0660 mmssms.db; [chcon](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon) u:object_r:radio_data_file:s0 mmssms.db;'*

Comment: ok. Rebooted and the SMS screen is blank but in the search bar in grey it says '1054 messages' which is the number of rows in mmssms.db - if I search contact names & phrases it returns results! But selecting one just opens the new sms window with <to> at the top. I checked the folder and a journal file has been created.

Comment: try to connect with [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31155) maybe it will read the modified database. or try another app like Textra. or maybe there are more flags in other tables